facing PlatformException when flutter run
i am new to flutter projects, and i'm working with the application already deployed.
after adding youtube_explode_dart to pubspec.yaml, there seems to be a problem.
when flutter run executed, i am encountering PlatformException Error and my flutter app just freezes at the splash screen(it only occurs in anroid devices, ios devices DO WORK FINE!!):
PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)


after logging, it turns out that some plugins are 'missing', but all plugins are at the proper location in my pubspec.yaml

Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method showToast on channel PonnamKarthik/fluttertoast)

here is my abbreviated main.dart (what i do here is just initializing some plugins):
void main() async {
  try {
    await initEnvironment();
    await initFireBase();
    startNHNCloudPushServiceChannel();
    await MarketingModule().init();
    await PhotoManager.clearFileCache();
    await initializeDateFormatting();
  } catch(e) {
   ...
  }

i've tried flutter clean & flutter pub get and re-run, but with no use.

check if the device is connected to Internet.

@MunsifAli it's all connected to Internet ;(
